# Identifying fewest locations from which to survey patch of habitat using QGIS viewshed?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed

We have a species which we know lives in a specific habitat. We have mapped that habitat across the landscape. We plan to put a VHF collar (radio-tracking collar) on some individuals. These collars work best if they have line of sight to a handheld receiver (up to a maximum of *c*.5km). We plan to go to certain locations in the landscape to scan for the collared individuals.

These scanning locations are usually picked intuitively, by going to the highest points that are easily accessible (e.g. on a road). It is a very time consuming process, and this seems pretty inefficient.

My method went like this: I am using QGIS Viewshed Analysis. I turned a map of roads into nodes. I then performed a viewshed analysis of those few thousand nodes, and overlaid it with the habitat map. This gives me the total quantity of habitat which is viewable from a road.

- Is it possible to identify the amount of habitat which is viewable from each location/node individually?
- Can we then identify the locations which see the largest amount of habitat with the smallest overlap?